# Не всегда передается $_POST из формы

Tags: php, html, form, action

Суть такова: есть файл, куда из формы передается через скрытое поле управляющее значение, указывающее, какую из функций использовать для обработки полученных данных из формы:

```
include '../script/config/app/config.php';
include '..' . CLASSES . 'article.php';
include '..' . CLASSES . 'page.php';
include '..' . CLASSES . 'basefunc.php';
/*получаем управляющее значение change_command*/
$action = isset($_POST['change_command']) ? $_POST['change_command'] : NULL;
switch($action)
{
case NULL:
    error_head(19);
break;
case 1:
    LogIn($_POST);
break;
case 2:
    $data = ["post" => $_POST, "files" => $_FILES];
    PriceList::Add($data);
break;
case 3:
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
    $result = Order::changestatus($id);
    switch($result)
    {
        case TRUE:
            return TRUE;
        break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
        break;
    }
break;
case 4:
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
    $result = Order::deleteorder($id);
    switch($result)
    {
        case TRUE:
            return TRUE;
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
            break;
    }
break;
case 5:
    $data = ["post" => $_POST, "files" => $_FILES];
    PriceList::Edit($data);
break;
case 6:
    ChangeLogPass($_POST);
break;
default:
    error_head(405);
break;
}
```

Вот пример кода формы:

```
<form action="/admin/core/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="change_command" value="2">
    <div class="part_1">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="main_screenshot">
                <div class="main_screenshot_preview">
                    <img id="preview_img">
                </div><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
                <label for="main_user_pic">Добавить файл<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="file" name="main_user_pic" onChange="preview(event.target)" required>
            </div>
            <div class="cost">
                <label for="site_cost">Стоимость:<span>*</span></label><br>
                <input type="text" name="site_cost" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notes">
            <label for="teg">Ключевые слова:<span>*</span></label><br>
            <textarea name="teg" required></textarea><br>
            <label for="short_note">Краткое описание:<span>*</span></label><br>
            <textarea name="short_note" rows="7" required></textarea><br>
            <label for="main_text">Полное описание:<span>*</span></label><br>
            <textarea name="main_note" rows="11" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="part_2">
        <div class="screenshots" id="screenshots">
            <div class="screenshot" id="screenshot_0">
                <div class="screenshot_preview" id="screenshot_preview_0">
                    <img id="screenshot_image_0">
                </div><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
                <label for="user_pic[0]" id="label_0">Добавить файл</label>
                <input type="file" name="user_pic[0]" id="user_pic_0" onChange="next(event.target)">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Проблема в следующем: не всегда передается $_POST из формы. Выполняется action, указанный в форме, но туда приходит пустой массив. Если честно, голова уже трещит от непонимания. Может, кто свежим взглядом увидит, в чем проблема?

Comment: Как осуществляется проверка заполнения массива $_POST? Попробуйте поставить вывод echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"; Не может он обнуляться в обработчике?

Comment: В обработчике убирал весь код, оставлял только var_dump($_POST); - как итог - приходит пустой массив

Comment: Может где-то есть AJAX-код, который отправляет данные методом GET? Попробуйте рядом с $_POST вывести еще массив $_REQUEST.

Comment: Аналогично - пусто.

Comment: А какой Web-сервер используете для разработки?

Comment: WampServer. Но такой сбой появился буквально пару месяцев назад, да и происходит он не всегда. И эта непостоянность меня и доканывает.